# Is this Django model schema convenient?

Tags: django, database-design

Let's say a Bar can be in multiple Zipcodes.

```
class State(models.Model):
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='cities')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Zipcode(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='zipcodes')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    zipcodes = models.ManyToManyField(Zipcode, related_name='bars')
    # cities = models.ManyToManyField(City, related_name='bars')
    # states = models.ManyToManyField(State, related_name='bars')
```

### Use case #1

```
# Duff zipcodes
>>> bar = Bar.objects.get(name='Duff')
>>> bar.zipcodes.all()
```

And also,

```
# 98101 bars
>>> zipcode = Zipcode.objects.get(value='98101')
>>> zipcode.bars.all()
```

Then, if I need to get the bar cities I would do

```
# Duff cities
>>> City.objects.filter(zipcodes__bars=bar).distinct() # ouch?
```

or maybe a property in Bar,

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def cities(self):
        return City.objects.filter(zipcodes__bars=self).distinct()

>>> bar.cities.all()
```

Adding "cities" m2m in Bar would really be,

```
>>> bar.cities.all()
```

However, why adding `cities` as m2m in Bar, if I already know the `cities` having the zipcodes?
I would need to mantain both m2m relationships.

- i.e. If add a zipcode to a bar, I may have to add a city (related to that zipcode) to the bar `cities`.
- i.e. If I remove a zipcode from a bar, I may have to remove a city (related to that zipcode) from bar's `cities`.

### Use case #2

Let's say we want to know all the zipcodes that have at least a bar,

```
>>> Zipcode.objects.filter(bars__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Or the cities that have at least a bar,

```
>>> City.objects.filter(zipcodes__bars__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Or the states that have at least a bar?,

```
>>> State.objects.filter(cities__zipcodes__bars__isnull=False).distinct()
```

I'm not sure if those queries are efficent and clean or is a better way to make them.
Maybe I could add custom Manager methods, so for example,

```
>>> City.objects.with_bars() # = City.objects.filter(zipcodes__bars__isnull=False).distinct()
```

So the main question is, do you think the Model schema relationships is good/convenient?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this looks well, as far as queries are concerned I don't think there is going to much deep nesting, may be 3 levels at most. So don't bother about it and many a times we try to pre-optimize things. Its ok but for now it is fine.

Comment: I'm just thinking about my main issue, supposing there are more levels like this?, i.e. `Planet -> Country -> State -> City -> Zipcode <-m2m-> Bar`... To grab the Planets that have at least a bar I would do, `Planets.objects.filter(countries__states__cities__zipcodes__bars__isnull=False).distinct()`. Is there any relational database theory/recipe recommendation to handle that case?

Comment: Planets ? Your application will be used on other planets of our solar system? Be reasonable about the use case. I don't see anything beyond Country is required to worry about as of now.

Comment: No, it was just an example if I continue nesting foreign keys. Should I have m2m in Bar to Planets, Country, State, City? If having m2m with Zipcode I can reach the others